# How to use React Test Utilities with Jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, reactjs

I made unit test code with test utils by React.
But encountered a problem

My environment is:

- Rails 4
- Jasmine 2.0.0
- Backbone 1.1.2

```js
describe("cNotice", function () {
    it("lol", function () {
        console.log(Notice); // present
        console.log(<Notice message="show me the message" />); // return Constructor

        var instance = <Notice message="show me the message" />;
        var component = React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(instance);
        expect(component.getDOMNode().childNodes[0].className).toBe('notice');
    });
});
```

Error message is:

> Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.

---

**UPDATE**

This code is no problem:

```js
describe("cNotice", function () {
    var Notice = null;
    beforeEach(function () { Notice = React.createClass({...}); });

    it("lol", function () {
        var instance = <Notice message="show me the message" />;
        var component = React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(instance);
        expect(component.getDOMNode().childNodes[0].className).toBe('notice');
    });
});
```

But I want to import Notice component from external file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

i used window namespace.
imported Notice component from external file

```js
describe("cNotice", function () {
    it("lol", function () {
        var component = React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(window.Notice({ message: "show me the message" }));
        expect(component.getDOMNode().childNodes[0].className).toBe('notice');
    });
});
```